# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous; Python; Model Comparison for Vulnerability Detection dataset

Tags: python

I am using Google Colab to train and test CNN and LSTM models. I keep getting this error.

This is my code for CNN model

```
def train_cnn_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, epochs):
    cnnModel = Sequential()
    cnnModel.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size = 1, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (1,1,128)))
    cnnModel.add(Flatten())
    cnnModel.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
    cnnModel.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    cnnModel.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data = (x_test, y_test), batch_size = 200, epochs = epochs, shuffle = True)
    model_json = cnnModel.to_json()
    with open('cnn.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    cnnModel.save_weights('cnn.h5')
    return cnnModel

x_train, y_train = get_cnn_data('training.csv')
x_test, y_test = get_cnn_data('testing.csv')
cnnModel = train_cnn_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, 150)
test_model(cnnModel, x_test, y_test)
```

Output:
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 2954
y sizes: 0
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Comment: Please provide a complete stack trace, it contains important information to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-84fc7edf0759> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 epochs = 10
      4 # Train the CNN model
----> 5 cnn_model = train_cnn_model(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, epochs)
      6 
      7 # Test the CNN model

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1958             )
   1959         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1960         raise ValueError(msg)
   1961 
   1962